# How to send previously uploaded files to controller?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am developing a web application where I stored my uploaded images into database in base64 format. When I resume application, I display previously uploaded Images on a web page. I need to submit the previously uploaded files to api. Can any one suggest me how I can achieve this?

Comment: Why would you base64 encode data in a database? Your problem is also really hard to understand without seeing your code, or maybe you could improve the question.

Answer (score -1):

Storing Images into a database is not an ideal solution.

A better option is to save the images at the web server and store its path or filename in the database. then just return the relative path to wherever required.

Still, if you want to send your database stored file to any place, then convert it to stream and then send it. If you need to send it to any API then send it as multipart form data.